# Accumulating and Ordering Child Actor Responses?

Tags: scala, akka

I'm new to Scala and Akka, and I've been reading a book on Akka. I can't find a reasonable solution for what I would think is a common use case with with Actors.

Lets say you have a parent actor that receives a request for a large chunk of work (Say you need to go to the network to download 100 files), and so the parent actor splits up the work and routes it to 10 children, so that we are downloading more than 1 file at once.

**Somehow I need to get all of the files back to the parent actor in order**. What would be a good design pattern for doing this?

[I found a link](http://www.ccri.com/2014/01/22/accumulating-responses-from-child-actors-and-transitive-message-ordering/) in my searching where they seem to have come up with a good way of accomplishing this, but because the blog don't actually show how to use the example (as they just providing a code snippet), and I'm a scala noob, I don't understand how to put it in practice: 
http://www.ccri.com/2014/01/22/accumulating-responses-from-child-actors-and-transitive-message-ordering/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with [akka futures](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html).  From your parent actor:

1. Create an array of 100 futures, each of which fetches one file
2. Use `Future.sequence` or `.traverse` to map the array of futures to a future of an array of files
3. map that to `.pipe` to send the array back to the parent actor

Each future could be the result of an `ask` to a pool of child actors, if fetching each file is best suited to an actor not a future.

Comment: This could be improved by replacing step 2 with `.reduce` and `.andThen` to traverse the array in-order as each task completes, and `pipe`ing the result (single download, or error) back to the parent actor as they complete.  Thus the parent can process individually and in order.I'll try to get a snippet later on..

Comment: Well, it's that basically all the files need to be in one place at one time. Sending each file back to the parent individually is no good unless I'm saving them in the actor, which I can't do if that actor is receiving multiple requests.

Comment: The Blog post I mentioned seems to mention that using ask is a bad way of going about it: "But there’s also the extra benefit, which I think people might be interested in more generally: we have removed a use of the ask pattern! Instead of asking — which implicitly sets up its own temporary actor which from the general way it’s written incurs certain performance penalties — we write our own Promise and fulfill it ourselves. We also know exactly when the temporary actor can shut itself down, allowing the ActorContext to dispose of it cleanly."

Comment: `ask` does create the extra actor per task; though for heavyweight tasks like downloading files, I see this as a reasonable overhead. Also, my original sol'n does not use `ask()`, only futures.

Comment: My original sol'n provides the array of all the files together; but if the array could be processed incrementally as the results were received, it would be acceptable to accumulate state (the array) in the parent actor.

Comment: Also, when using the futures, I need to be sure that I'm not blocking akka thread right? Or is that not a big deal?

Comment: Correct, is a big deal!  the download tasks should use their own [execution context](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/futures.html#Execution_Contexts) distinct from the system dispatcher.  The size of this pool governs the number of concurrent downloads, if using blocking i/o.